# How not to exit after JFileChooser OK pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

The scenario is, when a radiobutton is selected, I open a JFileChooser to select a DIRECTORY where SHOULD BE some files.
I'm trying to show an error message and I want to show again the directory chooser.
This is the code (the function I call when radiobutton changes):

```
private void JFileChooserOpen(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Select a directory");
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
// here I'm calling a function that searches for specific files. 
// true these files are found, false, they are not.
        if (checkTheDir(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()))
        {
// assigning the path to a label
                thePath.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
        }
        else
        {
// file not found
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File GuiRap not found!", 
                    "Controlla meglio", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
// what should I do, here, to open again the file dialog window?
// here I'm calling again this function, but surely is not a good practice!
            JFileChooserOpen(evt);
        }
// cancel button changes a radiobutton
    } else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        rbnParams.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Many thanks!
F.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating `JFileChooser`, override its `approveSelection` method ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#approveSelection%28%29)).

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser() {
    @Override
    public void approveSelection() {
        // test your condition here
        if (checkTheDir(getSelectedFile())
            super.approveSelection();
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File GuiRap not found!", 
                "Controlla meglio", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);                
    }
}
```

This way, file chooser doesn't close and reopen, but stays open until required condition is met (or cancel performed).

Also, you should provide a `parentComponent` for that `JOptionPane`, instead of giving it `null`.

Answer (score 0):

use a `do { } while` loop around your JFileChooser & JOptionPane, and instead of an error message, display a message like "Necessary file not found. Would you like to select a different directory?", use `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION` and quit if they say no

Comment: thank you, but this is not far for calling recursively the function.
and I think I can have stack error problems...

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
private void JFileChooserOpen(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Select a directory");
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    boolean valid = false;
    do {
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            valid = checkTheDir(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            if (valid) {
                thePath.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File GuiRap not found!", 
                    "Controlla meglio", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else {
            rbnParams.setSelected(true);
            valid = true;
        }
    } while(!valid);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not far for calling recursively the function.
and I think I can have stack error problems...

Comment: You will not have problems with call stack.